# How to check if the user entered input in input field has the string in format '10h' or '10m' using react and javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an input field. to this input field is the duration field.

so user can enter time liek below,

10h
10m

200h
40m and so on.

now i have to display a message if the user entered duration is invalid.
so when user enters say 10 or 200 or 40 then i should display message invalid.

below is my code,

```
function Parent() {
    return (
        <input 
            ref={inputRef}
        />
        <button onClick= {handleClick}>button</button> //on clicking this button should validate input field
    );
 }
```

how can i do it in javascript ?

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Could you use 2 inputs, one for hours and the other for minutes to make it easier for the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <input 
        ref={inputRef}
        pattern="/^[0-9]+(h|m)$/"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **regular expressions** that way you could even define **capture groups** that extract your hours and minutes.

See documentation for **RegExp** on mdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp